# Definition of the Second Order Partial Derivative from First Principles

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I was recently introduced to the wave equation and in the derivation of said equation they used the definition of the second order partial derivative for the final result. The source I used for the definition basically said that the following equation:
[image]

is the equivalent of:

[image]

And mentioned that this is because the partial second order derivative of `u` w.r.t `x` is defined as such.

I presumed that this meant if derived from first principles (taking `lim h->0`) for the definied formula one gets the second order partial derivative. However, I could not find an online resource which derives such a formula. I have tried to attempt this myself, however, I do not understand where the h squared term comes from.

If someone knows of the derivation, if they could kindly direct me to it, that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the insight can be seen just by seeing single variable derivatives:

$$ f' = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x+h) - f(x) }{h}$$

$$ f'' = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f'(x+h) - f'(x) }{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \frac{ f(x+2h) - f(x+h) }{h} - \frac{ f(x+h) - f(x) }{h} }{h}$$

Or,

$$ f'' =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x+2h) + f(x) - 2 f(x+h)}{h^2}$$

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense, I understand where I was making the mistake. Thank you.